# Torch CharStorage gives size zero (0)

Tags: lua, torch

I recently installed Torch using the instruction given [here](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html).

Everything looks to be installed fine, except when I use CharStorage. Here is my command line.

```
th> torch.IntStorage({1,2,3,4})
 1
 2
 3
 4
[torch.IntStorage of size 4]             [0.0003s]
th> torch.CharStorage('Hello World')
[torch.CharStorage of size 0]
```

I looked up this error message [here](https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/1064), but I don't know how  to fix it. Any help to solve this is really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to access `Storage` directly?

Comment: I have a binary file that I need to convert to a tensor. FloatStorage gives me the same problem as CharStorage. Here is the command I am using:

       x_train = torch.FloatTensor(torch.FloatStorage(filename.bin))

Comment: I just realized you're not talking about PyTorch. I'm removing the PyTorch tag; torch and PyTorch are different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly patch that fix (https://github.com/torch/torch7/commit/89ede3ba90c906a8ec6b9a0f4bef188ba5bb2fd8)
and reinstall torch.

Under your torch installation folder:

- Change 'pkg/torch/lib/TH/THAllocator.c' to include the fix mentioned
  in the patch above.
- ./clean.sh
- ./install.sh

Now, mapping file contents to memory should start working again.